# What can I use to fill gap between unpainted wood trim and wood sill?

Tags: trim

The gap is due to paneling install over drywall and I am re-installing trim around windows and door.  The trim only has clear coat, so painting caulking does not appear to be a solution here.

Comment: A picture of your conditions would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

Most silicone caulk manufacturers make caulks in a handful of tan colors:

[image]

If none of those colors match well enough, you could try looking for some wood putty. Some putty dries hard; some doesn't. [Here's one possibility.](http://www.hfstaples.com/Pages/Products/WoodTonePutty.htm)

Comment: Note that ALEX is acrylic latex with a little silicone added. It's not silicone, per se, which isn't paintable.